# simple javascript keystroke count

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, keystroke, onkeydown

I'm developing an online study/survey where I need to count the number of keystrokes that a participant makes. I am asking them to type lrlrlrlrlrlrl... in a text field to simulate walking. Turns out many of the participants (as evidenced by the time spent on the task) are copying and pasting.

I need something that will count keystrokes so I can identify participants who completed the task as requested. The study is programmed in Coldfusion and I was thinking about some sort of javascript/onkeydown/hidden file field combination, but I am not really a programmer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could use jquery to register on keyup events and count how many time this event was raised, so you would know how many keys have been pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kBJGM/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="nopaste"/>
<input type="text" id="countstroke"/>
<span id="count"></span>​
```

Javascript:

```
var strokeCount = 0;

$(function(){

    $(".nopaste").bind("copy paste", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#countstroke").keyup(function(){
        $("#count").text("Count: " + (++strokeCount));
    });
});​
```

If you want to take it a step further, you can enforce that only the L and R keys are registered (http://jsfiddle.net/kBJGM/5/):

```
$("#restrictivecount").keypress(function(e){
    var seq = rstrokeCount % 2;
    var allow = true;
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 76:
        case 108: // L or l
            if (seq == 1) allow = false;
        break;
        case 82:
        case 114: // R or r
            if (seq == 0) allow = false;
        break;               
        default:
            allow = false;
        break;               
    }

    if (allow)
        $("#rcount").text("Count: " + (++rstrokeCount));
    else
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This is two possible solutions to your problem. The first one prevents copy/paste. The second answer counts keystrokes, but they can still copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyPressCount = 0;

$(document).on("keydown",function(){
   keyPressCount++;
});
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9um23/)

Comment: Thanks! Another stupid question, but how do I get this into a form variable that I can pass to the database?

Answer (score -1):

```
count=0;

$(document).bind('keydown', function(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){
        case 39:
            alert('Right arrow was pressed');
            count++;
            break;
        case 37:
            alert('Left arrow was pressed');
            count++;
            break;
    }
});
```

You must have jQuery library to make this work.

Comment: bind is a function from jQuery

Comment: Yeah it is, its a method or function and not as you wrote a jQuery Plugin.