# how to count the number of times ctrl+alt+s is pressed in keyboard

Tags: javascript, keypress

I want an exe file running in background of a webpage and each timei pr ess ctrl+alt+s the counter should increase by one. Can i code in
 jscript or use shell script. If yes which tool to use and how to?

How to code it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111262/simple-javascript-keystroke-count

Comment: Do you already know that php is executed on server side? How will it work to count the number of key combination?

Comment: oops my bad! okay can you give some other insight

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple javascript keystroke count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111262/simple-javascript-keystroke-count)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting combination keypresses (Control, Alt, Shift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557990/detecting-combination-keypresses-control-alt-shift)

Comment: okay can i use tamper monkey for this? if yes can i use the follwing script document.addEventListener ("keydown", function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey  &&  zEvent.altKey  &&  zEvent.code === "KeyS") {
        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }
} );